# MySQL query that joins a table to 2 others

Tags: mysql

What I have is 3 tables (starred ids may be null):

```
ITEMS
id|name|cost

EVENTS
id|name|date|assignment|items

ASSIGNMENTS
id|name|start|items
```

where `ITEMS` contains lines of cost - an event may cost X and the assignment/project owning that event may have its own lines of cost. All Items in Events and assignments tables are referenced as comma separated lists of ids.

Given an Assignment, I'd like to get

```
ASSIGNMENTS.NAME|EVENTS.NAME|ITEMS.NAME|ITEMS.COST
Assignment A                 management  10.00
Assignment A     event A     travel exp  60.00
Assignment A     event A     day cost   100.00
Assignment A     event B     day cost    90.00
```

I tried the subquery way, building a subquery that returns a list of Items with

```
SELECT assignments.name, events.name, 
       concat(events.items, ",", assignments.items) 
  FROM assignments left join events 
  ON find_in_set(events.assignment, assignments.id) where assignments.id=2
```

but that way I would get the assignment item listed twice and, what's worst, I would get a line (assignment without event) with a field starting with comma.

I also tried joining twice the same table, but then MySQL remembered me that I cannot do it.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: If you have the ability to do so, please normalize your tables. I guarantee that it will save a lot of headaches in the future for you and whoever else touches this db

Comment: @zedfoxus I will. So far I have 30 tables and I've tried to be as granular and not redundant as possible. In this particular case I have no idea how to push it further. And my problem is still that I don't know how to join a table twice (like in this case: items joined to assignments and below, items joined to events).
Anyway, I'll push normalization as far as I can. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SELECT assignments.name, events.name, 
   concat(events.items, ",", assignments.items) 
FROM assignments left join events 
ON events.assignment = assignments.id
where assignments.id=2
```

Comment: I have the very same query in my attempts list. The problem is that it lists the "ITEMS" from assignments in every line containing events "ITEMS".

Comment: Please explain better